# Python list index out of range - finding local maxima

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization

I have a dataset and am trying to work out where there are peaks in the data; a data point with a higher value than the point before and after it.

I have code which works for one dataset but now transferring it to another dataset brings up index out of range error for certain lines.

The code I have is:

```
for line in file.readlines():
    peaks.append(0)
    line = line.split(',')
    time.append(float(line[0]))
    TP.append(float(line[3]))
    level.append(float(line[5]))


for i in range(len(level)-1):
    i = i + 1
    if (level[i] > level[i-1]) and (level[i] > level[i+1]):
        peaks[i] = 1
        noPeaks = noPeaks +1

print noPeaks
```

Yet for one line (so far) it says data is out of range - visually inspecting the data doesn't suggest this - the value is higher than the previous value but lower than the next so on a rising limb of the graph.

Any help would be great!

Comment: show us all of your code.  how you define `i`?

Comment: You seem to be trying to access an index one past the end of the list.  If `i` reaches the index of the last list item, `level[i + 1]` will try to access a list item that does not exist.  Show the whole loop, please!

Comment: When you have `level[i-1]` and `level[i+1]`, what will happen when `i` is either `0` or `len(level)-1` (i.e. max index)?

Comment: **what** does it say is "out of range"? **how** does it say it? To get anything out of error messages, you have to read them **carefully**.

Comment: As a side note, using NumPy this would (essentially) become `peaks = (level[1:-1] > level[:-2]) & (level[1:-1] > level[2:])`.

Comment: it says IndexError: list index out of range

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I cannot see your loop but the `(level[i] > level[i+1])` suggests that you are forgetting to put

```
for i in range(1,len(list)-1)
```

key to note there is that -1 since you're doing that +1 and the range only goes to max-1 anyway.

Starting your loop at 0 would not throw an out of bounds error since list[-1] is perfectly legal in python. however, i dont think you want your first comparison to be list[-1] > list[0]

---

Due to edit, 
You do not need to do the

`i = i + 1`

line in you're code, you will hit the length of the list because the for loop will also increment, causing an out of bounds error. Remove that line and it should work.

Comment: The OP is also getting item `i-1` in their check.

Comment: tis true, i put that in the loop but forgot to mention it :S thanks.

Comment: hang on, the negitave indice would NOT through an out of bounds error since python supports it.

Comment: That's true, but whether it gives the intended behavior is another matter.

Comment: True, but that's not the OP's problem, you confused me for a second there :P, i'll include the unwanted behaviour in my answer though, good thoughts.

Comment: thats ok :), remember to mark the right answer as an answer to make sure others know this has been answered and to help people with the same question :).

Answer (score 1):

If you're looping over a list `l  using`i`, then you should take to handle both the first and last points specially:

```
for i in xrange(1, len(l) - 1):
    # your check
```

Comment: for line in file.readlines():
 peaks.append(0)
 line = line.split(',')
 time.append(float(line[0]))
 TP.append(float(line[3]))
 level.append(float(line[5]))
 

for i in range(len(level)-1):
 i = i + 1
 if (level[i] > level[i-1]) and (level[i] > level[i+1]):
  peaks[i] = 1
  noPeaks = noPeaks +1
  
print noPeaks

Comment: @Chris: please edit that into your original question. Code snippets, esp. Python, are not readable in comments.

Answer (score 0):

When `i` is referring to the last element of `level`, `level[i+1]` will not exist and will raise `IndexError`.

Answer (score 0):

I've rewritten this taking into account other people's answers:

```
for line in file:
    line = line.split(',')
    time.append(float(line[0]))
    TP.append(float(line[3]))
    level.append(float(line[5]))

peaks = [0]*len(level)
numPeaks = 0
for i in range(1, len(level)-1):
    if level[i-1] < level[i] and level[i+1] < level[i]:
        peaks[i] = 1
        numPeaks += 1

print numPeaks
```